# Collection of styles for Plot/ListPlot

Tags: plotting, style

I'm trying to define my own collection of style commands so that I don't have to type them for all my `Plot`s and `ListPlot`s. The following works for `ListPlot`, but not for `Plot`.

Here is a minimal example:

```
mystyle = {Frame -> True, LabelStyle -> 14};
ListPlot[{1, 2}, mystyle]
Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 2}, mystyle]
```

I get the error:

> Plot::nonopt: Options expected (instead of style) beyond position 2 in
>   Plot[x^2,{x,1,2},style]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules.

Do you have any ideas why?
Thanks for your answers

Comment: `Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 2}, #] & @@ mystyle`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes about because `Plot` has the attribute `HoldAll`. `ListPlot` does not have that attribute so it won't have that problem.

The variable `mystyle` will be replaced with its definition in `ListPlot`, whereas `Plot` will try to parse `mystyle` – the atom, not its definition – as a style. `HoldAll` prevents `mystyle` from being replaced with its definition.

To state this with code, `ListPlot` will see

```
ListPlot[{1, 2}, {Frame -> True, LabelStyle -> 14}]
```

whereas `Plot` will see

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 2}, mystyle]
```

because `mystyle` is not evaluated in `Plot` since it has the `HoldAll` attribute.

You can allow the argument to be evaluated using `Evaluate`:

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 2}, Evaluate[mystyle]]
```

A slightly more advanced technique is to inject the value of the variable with `With`:

```
With[{s = mystyle}, Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 2}, s]]
```

This latter technique does not require `s` to evaluate. What happens is that `With` takes the expression in its second argument and replaces the symbol `s` before it evaluates the expression. Hence, `Plot` is not evaluated before it has been rewritten as

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 2}, {Frame -> True, LabelStyle -> 14}]
```